# ASP.NET C# - Insert a panel after a given panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I have a list of generated panels. When the user clicks on a panel, I would like to add another panel after the panel that the user clicked on.

I have the id of the clicked panel but I just can't figure out how to add the panel after a specific element. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How have you generated the panels? Please show the code. I would append the number of the panel to the ID(e.g. `panel_1`, ..., `panel_6`). Then you can recreate the panels in this order and delete or insert at this position. Or use a `Repeater` and delete from or insert into it's datasource.

Comment: Is this server-side or client-side?

Comment: I have generated the panels each with a unique ID which I pass through __doPostback(). In the onload I have used FindControl() to select the control and I would just like to add my panel after the selected one. Hope this clears it up for you Tim!